Unzip files, excluding files based on wildcard
I'm trying to extract all the files from a ZIP file, except for files with a specific extension.
Succeeds:
> unzip myzip.zip

Archive:  myzip.zip
  inflating: ...

Fails:
> unzip myzip.zip -x *.txt

zsh: no matches found: *.txt

How can I do this?

Quote the glob to stop the shell from trying to expand it:
unzip myzip.zip -x '*.txt'

